# Digital signature in Office 365 / Word Online?

Tags: office-js, office365-apps

Is it possible for an addin to add a **digital signature** to a Word Online document?

I'm using `office.js` for all of the operations, but I can't seem to find any reference about digital signatures on the Javascript nor in the documentation...

In the desktop version of Word 2016, there is the menu option to add a digital signature, and my addin's operations works in that Word version as well as in the Word Online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is not supported at this time. You can add feature request via the [OfficeDev UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) site.